# Right click->Browse ASP.NEt site in IIS6 don't work

Tags: iis-6

I created a simple Test website in my Windows Server 2003 server wich run IIS6. I have a simple Index.html file with some test text in it. I know i configured anything as needed because I did this before on other servers.

The problem is I can't access this Test site using the IIS Browser function or by typing http://localhost/test/ or http://test/ in IE.

- anonymous access is checked
- permissions to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test folder are all set to Full Control
- i also added Netwrok Service user to the permissions (this version on Server use Network Service user instead of ASPNET user or maybe I'm wrong because **there is not ASPNET user**)
- i also shared the folder for web from the folder properties and Web Sharing tab
- have .net 3.5 installed
- index.html is set as default document in the IIS site properties

There is nothing i have in my mind. The only thing I want is to be able to access the site from localhost by typing http://test/ in the browser

Comment: Do you have Index.html set as the default document? Have you tried directly accessing the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IIS and World Wide Web Publishing service is running.